# Short version: Error 14 error C2660: 'Player::addSpell' : function does not take 1 arguments

Tags: c++

I'm a slow learner to C++ here.  My game code is a text based RPG.  Here the player chooses to by a spell and add it to his spell book called 'Grimoire.'  Grimoire is a vector type that contains 'Spell' types as elements.  Spell is a struct type that has values such as it's name, damage range, MP, and price.  If the code snippet is too vague for the issue concerned see the original question titled:
Error 14 error C2660: 'Player::addSpell' : function does not take 1 arguments

The problematic line is:  Player.addSpell(mMagic[0]);

```
//Store.cpp
      ...       ...       ...

                    //If player already has the spell
                    if (Player.getSpellName() == mMagic[0].mSpell)
                    {
                        cout << "You already have this spell." << endl << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Increase size of Grimoire to store the purchased spell
                        Player.increaseGrimoire();

                        //Add spell to Grimoire

                        Player.addSpell(mMagic[0]); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM*******


//Player.H
class Player
{
public:
    //Constructor.
    Player();

    //Methods

    void addSpell(Spell magic);

private:
    //Data members.
vector<Spell>mGrimoire;

};


//Player.cpp
void Player::addSpell(Spell magic) 
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < mGrimoire.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (mGrimoire[i].mSpell == magic.mSpell)
            continue;
        else if (!(mGrimoire[i].mSpell == magic.mSpell))
        {
            mGrimoire[i] = magic;
            break;
        }

    }
}

//Store.h
 struct Store
{
public:

private:

    vector<Spell>mMagic;

};
```

Comment: Are you using "Player" as both a class name and a variable name? That will only cause confusion.

Comment: Just a class name hopefully.  I used it to tell C++ what the method belongs to.  I'm still trying to get my head around this to bare me.

Comment: Looking at the "long" version, it has `bool Store::enter(Player& Player)`, so you are using it for both. Do you have any errors before this one? It's important to fix errors top-down in every file.

Comment: I do but I'm not sure if they are related to this one.  I'm in the debugging process at the moment, but I will create an object for player and see how that goes.  Many thanks.

Comment: You have an object for the player - it's called "Player". (If you posted actual code and not a rewrite.) I don't think that is the cause of this error. Post the complete error message - your compiler should tell you what it thinks the prototype for `addSpell` is.

Comment: Error 14 error C2660: 'Player::addSpell' : function does not take 1 arguments c:\users\nigel\desktop\m1 l5 coding\m1 l5 coding\m1 l5 coding\store.cpp 77 1 M1 L5 Coding

Comment: 1>c:\users\nigel\desktop\m1 l5 coding\m1 l5 coding\m1 l5 coding\store.cpp(77): error C2660: 'Player::addSpell' : function does not take 1 arguments

Answer (score 1):

`Player` is a ***class*** and not an object. You need to create an object (an instance) of the `Player` class, and use that.

For example:

```
Player p;

...

p.addSpell(mMagic[0]);
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll give it a try.  However, this isn't the main file but the implementation file, 'Store.cpp' and I thought you only instantiate the player in the main file(game.cpp).  I hope I'm not confusing anyone here.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It's a good answer but my issue is more complex(or so it seems).  I have over 7 header files and over 7 source files for this program and there may be an overlap issue when including header files to both source and other header files.

Answer (score 0):

you need to instantiate an object(object of class Player) in order to call the member function(addSpell(Spell)).Only static member functions and staic member variables can be called with class name as they are class specific,member functions are object specific and hence you need to have an object instantiate to call them.

Comment: I instantiated an object 'Player p;'  but unfortunately I still get the same issue.  I think the problem lies elsewhere but thank you for your help.

Comment: can you update the question with latest code changes,so that it will be easy to pin point the real issue.

Comment: I think the issue lies elsewhere.  I have over 7 header files and over 7 source files for this program and there may be an overlap issue when including header files to both source and other header files.  Have you seen the original post?  It's titled:  Error 14 error C2660: 'Player::addSpell' : function does not take 1 arguments

Answer (score 0):

I think your real problem is that you need access to the same Player instance from many different modules.
 Usually for that you should store Player instance in your "game logic" module (that should be easily accessible from anywhere) and implement accessor to that instance.

Try something like this:

```
//Game.h
class Game
{
    ...
    private:
        static Game *instance;
        Player *player;
    public:
        static Game* getInstance();
        Player *getPlayer();
        Game::init();
}

//Game.cpp
Game* Game::instance = NULL;
Game* Game::getInstance()
{
    return instance;
}

void Game::init()
{
    ...
    instance=this;
    ...
    player = new Player();
    ...
}

Player* Game::getPlayer()
{
    return player;
}

//Store.cpp
...
    Player* player=Game::getInstance()->getPlayer();
    //If player already has the spell
    if (player.getSpellName() == mMagic[0].mSpell)
    {
        cout << "You already have this spell." << endl << endl;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        //Increase size of Grimoire to store the purchased spell
        player.increaseGrimoire();

        //Add spell to Grimoire

        player.addSpell(mMagic[0]); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM*******
    }
```

For more elaborate/aesthetic ways to handle such problems you should read about Design Patterns and Game Design/Programming Patterns.

Comment: That could be the case.  I have considered condensing the number of file/modules I have for this program.  Thank you for the pointers(no pun intended).